# Manipulable block hash by baker

Tags: tezos-client, blockchain, hash, random, oracle

Is the block hash a manipulable variable by a baker ? If not what about the value as a good source of randomness to use as a public verifiable random seed ?

Answer (score 1):

blockhash can be manipulated by every single endorser. It should be avoided to be used as source of entropy.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the block hash can be manipulated by the baker since it depends on all operations included in the block.
[How is the hash code of blocks generated?](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/1212/how-is-the-hash-code-of-blocks-generated)

The block hash would not be a good source for randomness for projects where a successful attack was worth the effort.

You could use [Acurast data providers](http://docs.acurast.com/integrations/tezos/). Join the telegram channel for more info: https://t.me/acurastnetwork

Comment: Hello, thank you for your input, but can you extend more your explanation please ? 

In my knowledge, the block have to be pre-baked. As such, the operations cannot be changed after the pre-commit. When the block will be endorsed, the endorsement and other data will be a part of the hash. So changing the operation after knowing the final hash result will end in a double bake process and that behavior will be slashed by the network.

Comment: This is a good thread your should look into: https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/1212/how-is-the-hash-code-of-blocks-generated

Comment: This thread is old and the consensus changed recently on Tezos. My team does not agree with this analysis... What about my previous explanation ?
It seems the only exploit is a restraint attack, but a slashing will be applied, of 10 xtz